# get_post_meta not working on publishing

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-field, post-meta

I'm building a notification system for a mobile app on Wordpress using One Signal.

Now Supposed to when I publish a new post sends a notification to all my Application devices.

The problem is I can't send post_meta with one signal notifications as it returns an undefined value first time when I hit the publish button.

But it works when I click update next time on the same post!! so why that delay/behavior?!

Same issue/behavior also with `get_field` for ACF plugin.

The code of the filter that one signal using:

```php
add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4);

function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    // Change the notification's title, message, and URL
    if($post->post_type == "mobile_notifications"){
        $fields['headings'] = array("en" => wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_title));
        $fields['contents'] = array("en" => wp_strip_all_tags($post->post_content));

        $fields['data'] = array( 'type' => 'product', 'data' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'prefix_hash_product' ) );

//            if ( !empty(get_field('target_product', $post->ID)) ) {
//                $fields['data'] = array( 'type' => 'product', 'data' => get_field('target_product', $post->ID) );
//            } elseif(!empty(get_field('target_category', $post->ID))) {
//                $fields['data'] = array( 'type' => 'category', 'data' => get_field('target_category', $post->ID) );
//            }
    }
    unset($fields['url']);

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: which variable is undefined ?

Comment: the get_post_meta return undefined when publishing or creating a new post, but it returns data when clicking update next, I noticed also it returns old data means if I change the metadata before click update after publish will return the first data I put when creating the post. **In other words**, **it's not getting the latest data saved on the database.**

Comment: [look the order of the different hooks](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L4018) maybe you save the meta values after the action `transition_post_status`.

Comment: I don't know but the title and the post content are getting fine, so why the post metadata delayed ?! 

So how I can edit my code ( witch hook? ) to avoid this odd behavior

Comment: If I do it by SQL instead of get_post_meta will work?

Comment: on which hook do you save the meta `prefix_hash_product` ?

Comment: it just custom post type with metabox done by the framework called MetaBoxes also I tried ACF same issue.

Comment: I tried also SQL `$wpdb->get_var("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'prefix_hash_product' AND post_id = $post->ID");` and same issue means the data didn't save yet when code run. how I edit this?

Comment: The one signal function uses this hook to send notification `transition_post_status` to get the data and send the notification

Comment: here https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/onesignal-admin.php